# Ignite partitioned cache performance and improvements if any

Tags: performance, ignite

I am trying to optimize the performance that I am experiencing by using Apache Ignite Partitioned cache mode and simple operations like filtering the cache based on certain values using SQL query seem to be slow for a relatively small sample size. The following is the setup details and timings -

Setup -

- Cache mode: Partitioned
- CPUs: 8 per node
- No. of servers: 5 (Ran this test from 1 to 10 nodes running 2 nodes per server)

SQL Query looks something like this - Select 5 columns based on filtering over a date column and 7 other integer columns of the cache (there are in total 30 columns in the cacheTable)

```
query = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 FROM cacheTable 
          WHERE dateColumn >= date1 AND dateColumn <= date2 AND filter1 = value1 
          AND filter2 = value2 AND filter3 = value3 AND filter4 = value4
          AND filter5 = value5 AND filter6 = value6 AND filter7 = value7");

cache.query(query).getAll();
```

The total number of records (or rows) in the cache is around **400K** and after filtering it returns **31K** records. The observed timings with respect to number of nodes are:

```
No. of nodes  Query Time (in ms)
1             317
2             215
3             171
4             176
5             126
6             114
7             96
8             92
9             133
10            125
```

Even after starting 10 nodes, we observe that a simple filtering query still takes around 92ms (the minimum of all). 
Are these timings expected? 
Are there any suggested configuration changes that might improve these numbers?

Our SLA is around 20 ms for this kind of filtering query. Is it possible to achieve this by improving the performance further?

Comment: Do you have indexes on fields that you filter? In what format do you store date?

Comment: Yes I have index on one of the columns which is a mandatory filter. Rest filter conditions are created on the fly and that can be any of the remaining columns. Hence I don't have indexing on all the other columns as too much indexing might also hamper the performance.

Comment: If you have primary or affinity key as part of the where clause, then Ignite will send the SQL request only to one affinity node. Otherwise, Ignite will broadcast the query to all nodes. Having said that, your timings are still too slow. It could be a JVM hotswap issue. Can you execute 1000 of queries in a loop and measure the time?

Comment: Another possibility is to use a replicated cache, in which case the query will go only to one of the nodes at all times.